# Changing parameter at database level

Tags: postgresql

When changing parameter at database level.
Example:

```
alter database db1 set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout to 0;
```

Is there a view that list the values of the parameters defined specifically for a database?

Answer (score 2):

No view, but the data can be found in the system catalog [`pg_catalog.pg_db_role_setting`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-db-role-setting.html). In `psql`, you can see them with the command `\drds`.